# Xamarin UITest "Unable to set fake location on iOS Simulator"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I am testing a Xamarin Forms app on Android and iOS using Xamarin.UITest. Since the application depends on the GPS location, I need to set a fake location. I do this using

```
App.Device.SetLocation(latitude, longitude)
```

...where `latitude` and `longitude` are variables of type double which contain the desired coordinates.

This works fine on Android but fails on the iPhone Simulator with the following exception:

```
SetUp : Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Unable to set location

ExitCode: 4

        -d,--device-id  <device-identifier> iOS Simulator GUID or 40-digit physical device ID
    set-location <latitude,longitude>
Expected lat,lng: Got 48,135831,11,573423
```

I did some research and found a thread on the Xamarin Forums which says that it might help to round the fake coordinates to only 4 digits after the decimal point but it didn't help. Apart from that, I tried to hardcode the coordinates and to use `float`s instead of `double`s but neither of the attempts worked.

What's going on there and how can it be fixed?

Here's my setup:

- Xamarin.UITest version 2.2.4
- iOS Simulator running iOS 9.3 on an iPhone 6
- Host computer: Mac mini running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

The same issue occurred several months ago with the following setup:

- Xamarin.UITest version 2.2.1
- iOS Simulator running iOS 11.2 on an iPhone X
- Host computer: Mac Mini running MacOS High Sierra (10.13.3)

At the time, I just left it alone, but now is the time where I need a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Expected lat,lng: Got 48,135831,11,573423`

It appears to be a bug in that Xamarin is using your local locale to convert those doubles to strings when they send them to simctl (and simctl is expecting decimal point-based strings *or* quoted decimals and thus it is parsing those are 4 separate numbers).

In your test code before setting the location, change the culture to `en-US` and set it back later to your actual culture if needed.

Something like this should work:

```
var currentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");"

// do some location setting / testing

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```